# P3 Assembly - Printing values of vector

Tags: assembly, vector, ascii, processador-p3

I have done a piece of code in P3 Assembly which iterates through a vector and prints all the numbers in that vector. The problem is that the code isn't printing the 9th value of the vector... and I cannot find the issue. Can someone help me? Here is my code:

```
; TEMPORIZACAO
DELAYVALUE      EQU     F000h

; STACK POINTER
SP_INICIAL      EQU     FDFFh

; INTERRUPCOES  (INTERRUPTS)
TAB_INT0        EQU     FE00h
TAB_INT1        EQU     FE01h
MASCARA_INT EQU FFFAh

; I/O a partir de FF00H
DISP7S1         EQU     FFF0h
DISP7S2         EQU     FFF1h
LCD_WRITE   EQU FFF5h
LCD_CURSOR  EQU FFF4h   
LEDS            EQU     FFF8h
INTERRUPTORES   EQU     FFF9h
IO_CURSOR       EQU     FFFCh
IO_WRITE        EQU     FFFEh

LIMPAR_JANELA   EQU     FFFFh
XY_INICIAL      EQU     0000h
FIM_TEXTO       EQU     '@'


ORIG    8000h
VarTexto1       STR     'Valores do vector: ',FIM_TEXTO


ORIG    8030h
vetor   STR  67, 13, ffddh, 99, 12, 112, FFA6h, 65, 6AFFh
; 67, 13, -35, 99, 12, 112, -90, 65, 27391

 ORIG    0000h
 JMP     inicio

LimpaJanela:    PUSH R2             ; **CLEAR SCREEN
            MOV     R2, LIMPAR_JANELA
    MOV     M[IO_CURSOR], R2
            POP R2
            RET

PrintVec:   PUSH    R1
            PUSH    R2
            PUSH    R3
            PUSH    R4
            PUSH    R5
            MOV     R5, M[SP+8]   ; Pointer to the start of the string
            MOV     R2, M[SP+7]   ; Location of the first XY character
            MOV     R4, M[SP+9]   ; Pointer to the first elemnt of the vector
            MOV     R3, M[SP+10]  ; Size of the vector
Ciclo:      MOV     M[IO_CURSOR], R2
            MOV     R1, M[R5]
            CMP     R1, FIM_TEXTO
            BR.Z    Write
            CALL    EscCar
            INC     R5
            INC     R2
            BR      Ciclo
            ADD     R2, 1
Write:      CALL    PrintNum
            INC     R4
            ADD     R2, 6
            DEC     R3
            BR.NZ   Write
            POP     R4
            POP     R3
            POP     R2
            POP     R1
            RETN    2                ; Actualiza STACK

PrintNum:   PUSH    R1
            PUSH    R3
            PUSH    R5
Convert:    MOV     R3, 10
            MOV     R5, M[R4]
            ADD     R5, R0
            BR.NN   LABEL2
            MOV     M[IO_CURSOR], R2  
            MOV     R1, '-'
            CALL    EscCar
            NEG     R5
 LABEL2:    ADD     R2, 4
 LABEL3:    MOV     M[IO_CURSOR], R2      
            DIV     R5, R3
            MOV     R1, R3
            ADD     R1, 48
            CALL    EscCar
            MOV     R3, 10
            DEC     R2
            CMP     R5, 0
            BR.NZ   LABEL3
            POP     R1
            POP     R3
            POP     R5
            RETN    2                ; Actualiza STACK

EscCar:     MOV     M[IO_WRITE], R1
            RET                     

;===============================================================================
;                                Programa prinicipal
;===============================================================================
inicio:     MOV     R1, SP_INICIAL
            MOV     SP, R1
            CALL    LimpaJanela         ; Clear screen
            PUSH    9
            PUSH    vetor
            PUSH    VarTexto1           ; Push parameters onto stack
            PUSH    XY_INICIAL          ; Push parameters onto stack
            CALL    PrintVec
;===============================================================================
```

Comment: ...what assembly language is this?  It looks a bit like 8081, maybe?  Something from a university?  Invented by your professor?

Comment: Yup...its a P3 simulador from university....http://algos.inesc-id.pt/arq-comp/?Material_Did%C3%A1tico___Processador_P3

Comment: The manual is in portuguese, so that's not of much help. What does the `STR` directive do? Judging by the way you've declared `vetor` (and the comment below it) it seems like each element is at least 16 bits in size. But in the `Write` loop you appear to treat the elements as single bytes, since you only do `INC R4` when increasing the address.

Comment: @Michael It seems to be a 16-bit processor with a 16-bit address bus.  An increment of one moves to the next addressable word.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `PrintNum:` does not `PUSH` and `POP` register `R2`, the cursor position for output. It fiddles with `R2` in ways not immediately obvious. This is only a guess, but it causes the text alignment to go off such that the 9th element is not visible.

So add `PUSH R2` and `POP R2` on entry/exit of `PrintNum:`

As an aside: you *must* document your functions' register arguments on entry, and registers altered at exit. It's a basic noob failure not to.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in the use of the instruction **RETN**. In the the function **PrintVec** should be **RETN 4**, because you're getting four values from the stack (when you do **MOV R5, M[SP+8]/ MOV R2, M[SP+7]/ MOV R4, M[SP+9]/ MOV R3, M[SP+10]**, etc.). In the function **PrintNum**, you only need to have the instruction **RET**, because you're not getting any values from the stack